# Pause Android app-flow

Tags: java, android, android-alertdialog

When a return button is pressed in the app I am working on:

```
public void clickReturn(View view)
{
    // ...

    // Call an event handler before finishing the activity
    _appData.CustomDetail.hookBeforeFinish(this, new ArrayList<CompSubmission>(_submissions));

    // Finish this activity
    finish();
}
```

I am not able to modify `clickReturn()` - the way the application is structured, all I have access to is the hook `hookBeforeFinish()`.

What I want to do is add a dialog to prompt for some input. I can do this in `hookBeforeFinish()`, but it only appears for a split second. I assume what is happening is I set up the `AlertDialog` builder, call `builder.show()` but `finish()` is being called directly afterwards - so the dialog only appears momentarily.

Is there anything I can put after `builder.show()` in the hook function such that it won't continue execution to `finish()`? If I can pause the application flow until someone presses the OK button on the dialog thatwould work better for me.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Please comment `finish()`.

Then read and add a dialog as explained [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html). In your positive button click (e.g. OK button), add `finish();`

**Edit**
Since you cannot override `clickReturn()` or change the class, you can use your `hookBeforeFinish()` to create a dialog and comment 'clickReturn();' line.

In your dialog, in the listener for the button which expects to finish the activity add `clickReturn();`.

This way you will pause the activity closing until user decides to do so.

Comment: As I said, I am not able to modify the class with `clickReturn()` in it so I need a solution that is self contained within the hook function.

Comment: Then can you call `hookBeforeFinish()` and comment calling `clickReturn()`? If you can, then create your dialog there, and then add `clickReturn()` in your dialog button click listener.